# Replace all full stops with underscores in a string android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to replace all the full stops `.` with underscores `_` in email address for which I'm using

```
String email = userEmail.replaceAll("."  ,  "_");
```

like `abc.d@xyz.com` should become `abc_d@xyz_com`

but instead it returns "____________"

Thanks in advance! Have a good day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use replace as mentioned above or if you still want to use replaceAll then escape character like below.

```
String email = userEmail.replaceAll("\\."  ,  "_");
```

Comment: but full stop isn't an escape character. is it?

Comment: @AwaisMajeed no it isn't. However, it is a *special character in regex*, which means **any character**

Comment: When we use replaceAll then '.' is considered as regular expression, so it will replace all characters. If not familiar with regex, read little of it. For ex: If you use String email = userEmail.replaceAll("@"  ,  "_"); then no escape is required. Also, Pavneet edited his answer later.

Answer (score 2):

use `userEmail.replace("."  ,  "_");`

because with `replaceAll` , `.` will work as `regex` expression mean any character so your whole string will be replaced with `_`

or you can escape the `.` to make it work as a literal

```
String email = userEmail.replaceAll("\\."  ,  "_");
```

A simple example would be , suppose you want to replace any 3 character followed by `abc`  then [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) accepts first input as `regex`

```
"9a%abc.d@xyz.com".replaceAll("...abc", "_") //_.d@xyz.com
```

where `...` match any three characters and followed by `abc`

[Read more about Regex Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Comment: Thanks...it worked.....but how are they two different can you please explain a little bit??